# Python Partial Class Inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a problem where I want my `def transfer(self,amount):` to inherite *only* the `self.__balance` from the parent class and not also the other values.

```
class Konto:

  def __init__(self,number,owner,bday,adress,opened,balance):
    self.__number = number
    self.__owner = owner
    self.__bday = bday
    self.__adress = adress
    self.__opened = opened
    self.__balance = balance

  def get_Kontostand(self):
    return "Kontostand:" + str(self.__balance)

  def set_Kontostand(self, new_balance):
    self.__balance = new_balance
    return self.__balance

  def Einzahlung(self, insert):
    self.__balance = self.__balance + insert

  def Auszahlung(self, outtake):
    self.__balance = self.__balance - outtake

class Girokonto(Konto):
  def __init__(self,creditlimit,overdraft,interest,number,owner,bday,adress,opened,balance):
    self.__creditlimit = creditlimit
    self.__overdraft = overdraft
    self.__interest = interest
    super().__init__(number,owner,bday,adress,opened,balance)

  def set_Kreditlimit(self, new_creditlimit):
    self.__creditlimit = new_creditlimit

  def Überweisung (self, amount):
    self.__balance -= amount
```

For the sake of readability I deleted some get/set methods.
My problem is the last line, if I'm trying to execute:

```
Test = Girokonto(1500,5,1,17033,"Name",21,"Street",24,4900)
Test.Überweisung(20)
```

It returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Konto.py", line 96, in <module>
    Test.Überweisung(20)
  File "C:\Users\Konto.py", line 92, in Überweisung
    self.__balance -= amount
AttributeError: 'Girokonto' object has no attribute '_Girokonto__balance'
```

Because it says that the attribute is missing I tried to inherite it form the Konto class with:

```
def Überweisung (self, amount):
    super().__init__()
    self.__balance -= amount
```

Which isnt working because it says the the **init**() is missing six positional arguments.
If I just insert them in the **init**() brackets it isnt working, because:

```
super().__init__(number,owner,bday,adress,opened,balance)
NameError: name 'number' is not defined
```

If I also insert it in the Überweisung(), then I also have to insert these arguments in my command, and even then I receive the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Girokonto' object has no attribute '_Girokonto__balance'
```

My last idea was to try it without the self. before __balance, but the answer to that is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable '_Girokonto__balance' referenced before assignment
```

I have no idea how to continue on that.
Is it somehow possible just to inherite the value of self.__balance to the sub class?
It is important that after executing Test.Überweisung() I am still able to do things like Test.Einzahlung() and that the balance value is the same for Test in class and subclass.

Comment: Don't use `__*` double-underscore names; their stated use-case is to make them *class private*, so that the same name in a subclass won't clash. If you *want* the name to be available to subclasses, you did exactly the wrong thing.

Comment: Note that Python doesn't have a privacy model like Java does, there is *no point* in trying to hide attributes from outside eyes. Double-underscore names are not giving you that kind of privacy, and are hurting you here. Use single-underscore names instead (still only a convention).

Comment: Yeah, I know that this makes them private, but it's a university task and they said it exactly like this. Make them private and create a subclass. Thats why I m so confused and dont know how to solve it.

Comment: You made them class private. If the university did not state to use double underscores explicitly, they want you to use single underscores instead.

Comment: They stated explicitly that they want double underscores, but thanks for the answer and the link. Thats enought for me to continue.

Comment: Then you'll have to go and have a chat with your professor about this assignment.

Comment: How are `Auszahlung` and `Überweisung` any different? Can't you just do `self.Auszahlung(amount)` in your `Überweisung`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I summon you to reconsider the duplicate. It might be just an XY problem, and he's supposed to use the `Auszahlung` method from the parent class instead. Maybe add some custom functionality to it, to make sure it doesn't go over a balance limit or something, but still.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I suppose that you are right and I can just use the Auszahlung. Did thought about that myself but would it be possible to to that if I use douple underscope?

Comment: @J.Wick Yes, your parent class's `Auszahlung()` can still access the dunderscore variables defined in the parent class.

Comment: Honestly, this is an assignment where your professor knows Java or C++ and is trying to apply them to Python. Yes, it's *somewhat possible* with dunderscore attributes, but that's absolutely not what you're supposed to do with Python. But yeah to complete the assignment, you can just use `Auszahlung()`, just know that in reality you could just make the attributes *not* dunderscore, and it would work just fine.